# Which one is correct? (Usage of "reach" vs. "arrive")

Tags: word-choice

> The boys are about to reach.
>
> The boys are about to arrive.

When should I use *reach* and when should I use *arrive*?

Comment: "The boys are about to reach." sounds wrong because it is missing the location they are reaching. ('reach' requires a direct object). 'arrive' implicitly refers usually to 'here' (the location of the speaker, or the location in the context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Reach is transitive when referring to a destination, meaning it needs a direct object.  So you want to say

> The boys are about to *arrive*.

Or, you could say

> The boys are about to *reach their destination*.

Comment: "The plane arrived on time"or "The plane reached on time"

Comment: The plane arrived in time or The plane reached in time

Comment: "The plane *arrived* on time," or "the plane *reached the terminal* on time," not, "the plane *reached* on time."

Comment: When you use _reach_, you most always need to follow it with the place (the "where") that the subject reached: _it reached the terminal_, _he reached the finish line_, etc.

Comment: @aliya: In the context of a plane arriving, "on time" refers to it getting there at its scheduled time (*It was due to arrive at six o'clock, and it arrived on time*). "In time" means "with enough time for (something)" - for example, *The plane arrived in time for us to reach the theatre before the start of the show*.

Comment: There is also a subtle nuance of perspective.  To a person at the origin, the boys leave and then reach their destination.  To a person at the destination, the boys arrive.